# Chord in Bach's chorale

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, j-s-bach, chord-inversions

This is a part of Bach's chorale R.311. I am unsure of the starred chord. It uses a passing note in it as well. 
[image]

*According to me, I think this chord is* **A°/C, with the D as an accented passing note.** Is this correct?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93580/discussion-on-question-by-grace-chord-in-bachs-chorale).

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. An answer should go on an answer post. Comments are to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the comments has been moved to chat with the argument that an answer should be posted as an answer not a comment. That makes sense.

So there should be an actual answer and I will post the answer here as it appeared in the comments:

Yes it is correct that the chord is A°/C, with the D as an accented passing note.

Answer (score 0):

An A diminished in first inversion (over C) - the D is an accented (on a down beat) passing note.